# Querying with SDK2.0: OR filters together

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, rally

This example in the documentation shows how to query the Rally WS API, using a single item in a filters array:

```
Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
    model: userStoryModel,
    fetch: true,
    filters: [
        {
            property: 'ScheduleState',
            operator: '<',
            value: 'Accepted'
         }
   ],
...
```

I know if I have a second filter to the filters array, it AND's the two filters together.  But how would I OR two filters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Rally.data.QueryFilter's or method](https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p/doc/#!/api/Rally.data.QueryFilter-method-or) to do this:

```
filters: [
    Ext.create('Rally.data.QueryFilter', {
        property: 'ScheduleState',
        operator: '=',
        value: 'Accepted'
    }).or(Ext.create('Rally.data.QueryFilter', {
        property: 'ScheduleState',
        operator: '=',
        value: 'Defined'
    })
]
```